# Tracking down android memory usage with MAT

Tags: android, android-image, android-memory

I'm trying to work out where some of the memory usage of my app is coming from using MAT.

There's some references that to bitmaps which seem to retain a lot of heap. Is there any way to determine what actual resource they are? The images generally coming from drawables within the app. There's object references, but I can't work out how to drill down to determine which actual drawable may be taking up the memory.

[image]

E.g. there's a Bitmap with a retained heap of over 1mb and lots over 300k

Comment: If you trace the GC roots, you can see what is holding onto the bitmap, which may help you identify where it came from.

Comment: @CommonsWare is that "Path to GC roots" and then is "all references the best thing to look at"?

Comment: There should be something like "all references except weak/soft" or something like that that would be a bit better, but basically you have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Define your real problem. `Bitmap`s of these size are quite normal: between 200x200px and 500x500px or so.

If you have `OutOfMemoryError`s, when first approaching app I like to use histogram (second icon, with 3 blue bars) and filter on `your.package.*Activity`. If there are too many instances, that possibly means there is a memory leak.

Comment: The issue is that my app seems to consume a lot of memory (typically 25-40mb), but I've had reports from users of it getting up to 100mb+. There's no really big images within the app. I think the biggest is about 20k so I'm guessing I'm not clearing something up correctly and stopping a GC taking place on some objects. I know some users get an OOM, but I've not seen one myself